# Use Glide.Xamarin with Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, android-glide

How to use Glide.Xamarin with Xamarin.Forms (Portable), I am not sure how to use it with Cross-Platform, can someone please help me with Glide.Xamarin

Or is there any other way to use GIF in Xamarin.Forms (Portable)?

Comment: `Glide` is an Android only library. You could use Xamarin.Form's based dependency services to access and execute code within your `Xamarin.Android` project : https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/dependency-service/

Comment: In terms of a simple way to show a GIF image in Forms, display it in a `WebView`

Comment: In the WebView I am getting background also, I don't want the background in GIF image.

Comment: Set the html background to transparent : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42328699/transparent-webview-in-xamarin/42330230#42330230

Comment: Rather try Xamarin `Universal Image Loader`