# Transparent WebView in xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, webview, xamarin.android, background-color

I searched Transparent WebView but I could not find any answer for my problem.

I have these:

```
    string str = "Hello. How are you? I am fine.";
    String s = "<html><head><style type='text/css'>body {"
            + "text-align: justify;}</style></head><body dir = rtl>"
            +str
            + "</body></html>";
    webview.LoadDataWithBaseURL("", s, "text/html", "utf-8", null);





<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/webView1"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

With thanks

EDIT:

Thank you SushiHangover
I used your help and I edited "s". Now I do not have any problem. Thank you.

```
string str = "Hello. How are you? I am fine.";
String s = "<html><head><style type='text/css'>body {background-color:#00000000;"
        + "text-align: justify;}</style></head><body dir = rtl>"
        +"<font style='opacity:0.79'>"
        + "<font color='white'>" + str + "</font>"
        + "</body></html>";
```

Comment: Are you using emulator. Webview don't work on emulators.  Try a real device.  I use Webviews on my app too

Comment: Yes. I use emulator.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1) Do **not** set a background color in the layout axml:

```
<android.webkit.WebView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/webView" />
```

2) Set the background color in html:

```
<body style='background-color:#00000000;'>
```

3) Set the background color of the `WebView` at runtime:

```
WebView.SetBackgroundColor(Color.Transparent);
```

4) This should work on most API level and `WebView` version combinations, if you find a combination that does not work you will also need to turn of hardware acceleration, but typically this is only needed for old API version (i.e. 2.x/3.x...) and I would typically not recommend in turning acceleration off...

```
WebView.SetLayerType(LayerType.Software, null);
```

#### Example:

```
string htmlContent = "Hello. How are you? I am fine.";
string htmlString = @"
    <html>
        <head>StackOverFlow</head>
        <body style='background-color:#00000000;'>
            <div>
                " + htmlContent + @"
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
";
webview.SetBackgroundColor(Color.Transparent);
webview.LoadDataWithBaseURL("", htmlString, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```